# IntelliJ multiline ternary indentation

Tags: intellij-idea

My indentation setting is set to one tab. However, when I format my code, multiline ternary operators are formatted with two tabs indent (should be one tab there as well). See below.

[image]

These are the only related settings I can find and tweaking them doesn't seem to change the indentation.

[image]

These are my indentation settings:

[image]

Is there another setting to control this?

Answer (score 2):

You may configure these settings in Preferences | Editor | [Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/settings-code-style.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2019.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product) | Language | Tabs and Indents.

The "Indent" and "Continuation Indent" attributes must be set to "1" in your case.

Comment: I've updated the question with my Tabs and Indents settings. If I change "Indent" and "Continuation indent" to 1, the formatting breaks everywhere else in the file. Our project uses two tab indent and I want IntelliJ to display single tab indent. Any advice?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please open settings "Preferences | Editor | **[Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/settings-code-style.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2019.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product)**" unmark the fields **[Enable EditorConfig]** and **[Detect and use existing file indents for editing]** and check formatting once again? 

If the problem remains, please create a new request on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?_ga=2.239493383.500899450.1581315433-1923750048.1580727048) to investigate it.

Comment: Problem remains.